# one workflow to set datetime to current date if case status is open and if changes to some other state then the field becomes null

Tags: workflow

[image: **enter image description here**]

I have set the field update[casedate__c]to NOW() whenever the case is in open/reopen state.

Now when the case changes to some other state then i should  make it null...
IS it possible to do in one workflow??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also achieve this through WorkFlow but you have to create 2 workflows for your criteria, so better to create 1 Process Builder

Create a Process builder with two criteria

1. Criteria 1 for status open and action according to your requirement.
2. Criteria 2 for status close

if 1st criteria is false it will automatically switch to next criteria and perform the respective Action.

[image: Create your process builder like this and add actions accordingly]

Answer (score 0):

No, You have to do it through Process Builder.